# laravel display only specific column from relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have read a few topics about this, but they managed to solve my problem partially ...

this is my controller

```
class DeskController extends BaseController{

public function getDeskUsers($deskId){
    $user = DeskUserList::where(function($query) use ($deskId){
        $query->where('deskId', $deskId);
    })->with('userName')->get(array('deskId'));

    if (!$user->isEmpty())
        return $user;
    return 'fail';
}
```

this is the model

```
class DeskUserList extends Eloquent {

  protected $table = 'desk_user_lists';

  public function userName(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'userId')->select(array('id','userName'));
  }
}
```

the method getDeskUsers may returns ALL the DeskUserList table records, related with the User table record `(on deskUserList.userId = User.id)`.

practically I want each record returned is composed of:

> DeskUserList.deskId
>
> User.userName

eg. `[{"deskId":"1","user_name":antonio}]`

What i get is

```
[{"deskId":"1","user_name":null}]
```

As you can see the user name is a null value...

BUT

if I edit my controller code:

```
->with('userName')->get(array('userId')); //using userId rather than deskId
```

then i get

```
[{"userId":"2","user_name":{"id":"2","userName":"antonio"}}]
```

By this way I still have two problem:

- the userId field is twice repeated
- I miss the deskId field (that I need...)

hope be clear, thanks for your time!

Comment: You need to `select` foreign key and referenced primary key, so Eloquent is able to match related model with its parent. Anyway, this is probably wrong way of doing it anyway. So first specify why you need that `select`?

Comment: the table desk_user_list is like a pivot table... it has basicaly 3 fields: id(PK), userId(FK) and tableId(FK). As you can imagine it represents a list of user seted on every table. So following the schema id> (userId deskId) an example of value could be:
1> (7 6);
2> (4 6);
3> (2 6);
4> (5 8);
5> (1 8);
that means we have users 7, 4 and 2 seated on table 6 and users 5,1 seated on table 8

now I want to get all the user name seated on each table

eg 
7> 6;
4> 6;
2> 6;
5> 8;
1> 8;

thats is what I want as response...

Comment: Check my answer, this is what you need. If you have questions, feel free

Comment: Yes I do...I do not understand, sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `belongsToMany`, no need for a model representing that pivot table.

I assume your models are `Desk` and `User`:

```
// Desk model
public function users()
{
 return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'desk_user_list', 'deskId', 'userId');
}

// User model
public function desks()
{
 return $this->belongsToMany('Desk', 'desk_user_list', 'userId', 'deskId');
}
```

Then:

```
$desks = Desk::with('users')->get(); // collection of desks with related users

foreach ($desks as $desk)
{
  $desk->users; // collection of users for particular desk
}

// or for single desk with id 5
$desk = Desk::with('users')->find(5);
$desk->users; // collection of users
$desk->users->first(); // single User model
```

Comment: I think your answer make me understand how pivot table works in laravel... But I think I cant use your solution becouse in desk_user_list table I also have the timestamps and softDelete fields, that I use to remove a user from a table when his session is expired... but maybe there are some other way to do that...thx!

Comment: Just use `withPivot([ ..fields you need go here.. ])` on the relation definition and it will be accessible through `$desk->users->first()->pivot` - of course you don't need `first` it's just an example